# Cylinder Normals

Tags: opengl, graphics, normals

I'm developing an OpenGL application which right now only draws a big tube consisting of several small cylinders (kind of like a slinky). I'm getting an annoying effect when I turn the lighting and normals on, as from certain angles I get these annoying black dots on the cylinders' borders:

[image: Black dots on individual cylinders borders]

I belive this is a byproduct of the fact the cylinders are very thin. Basically I set the normal to (0,0,+/- 1) when setting the top/base, and then side normals are (cos(toRadian(beta)), sin(toRadian(beta)), 0).

Is it possible to remove this effect whitout getting 'fatter' cylinders? Or is there something wrong in the way I define the normals?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like lighting is enabled from that image. And do you need to draw the top and the bottom of each cylinder at all? Also, are there any scale matrices in effect?

Comment: The light is far away so they are all equally lit (thus looking flat, this pic is looking at the cylinders almost perpendicular to their top/base). And no, there are no scale matrices in effect. (and yes, I need the top bottom, else I'd end up with a hollow tube which I don't want). EDIT: could it be that it is due to a lack of anti-aliasing, or something in those lines, and thus those borders looking jagged?

Comment: More likely you haven't enabled face culling?

Comment: Having face culling on/off doesn't make any difference... those annoying glitches are still there..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the rendering of the sides of the cylinders. The yellow in the image corresponds to the tops of the cylinders. The sides of the cylinders are at 90 degrees to the tops, so they are not lit (I'm guessing the light is in the same direction as the camera) and appear black. With the cylinders being so thin these will not fill make pixels so they don't show up much.

How to fix it? I've got a couple of ideas:

1) Just draw the tops and bottoms, not the sides - this will definitely fix the problem when viewed from this angle, but will lead to further problems if your camera moves.

2) Disable lighting, then all faces will be drawn the same colour (assuming the sides are the same colour as the top).

3) Use multi-sampling - this means most of the edges won't appear (as each pixel is more likely to be top than side due to the angle).

4) Add more lights around the scene, perpendicular to the current light.

1 & 2 are your best bet depending on what you're trying to achieve.